# Are reported messages deleted after they get reviewed?

Tags: xbox-one

I was playing on xbox and someone messaged me using a lot of curse words. I cursed back and my message got deleted and I received a short suspension.

After seeing this I went back through and reported all of his messages where he cursed at me. Even though he said some much worse things I noticed none of his messages have been deleted.

Were the messages deemed okay for some reason or do messages not show up as deleted to the other person?